# How to remove white stains from Lumina Dashboard?

Tags: car, cleaning, interior

Today I noticed that my Lumina 2008  has some white stains on the dashboard. Previously I used to gently wipe it with soft cloth with tap water. But now I started to clean it with drinking water and not the tap salty water...

As you can see the dashboard it has spots - is there a way to remove them?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They may be hard water spots. I would try some diluted vinegar applied with a soft cloth. If need be increase the strength of vinegar if some are stubborn. Once it is clean apply an automotive plastic treatment available at auto parts suppliers.

Comment: Thanks, I used the vinegar and for two days it worked but it seems those spots are coming back. Can you recommend any plastic treatment ???